# Herkunft und Schreibung von »Heiopei«

Tags: etymology, colloquial, spelling

*Heiopei* bezeichnet zumindest in einigen Regionen Deutschlands umgangssprachlich eine unzuverlässige, verplante, unfähige oder dumme Person.

Zur Herkunft habe ich bisher nur einige spekulativ wirkende Quellen gefunden, die es auf [*eiapopeia*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eiapopeia), was wiederum teilweise auf [Onomatopoesie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoesie), teilweise aufs Altgriechische zurückgeführt wird. Deswegen ist meine erste Frage: Hat jemand eine **zuverlässige** Quelle zur Herkunft dieses Wortes?

Verwandt damit ist die zweite Frage: Gibt es eine etymologisch sinnvolle Schreibung dieses Wortes und falls ja, wie lautet sie? Denkbar wären z. B. *Heiopei, Haiopei, Hajopei,* usw. (Ich habe das Wort bisher noch nicht in einem Rechtschreibwörterbuch gefunden.)

Comment: »Heiopei« habe ich noch nie gehört (aufgewachsen in Graz, seit 20 Jahren in Wien). Ich kenne nur »Eia Popeia« z.B. im Kinderlied »Eia Popeia, was raschelt im Stroh«. »Eia Popeia« ist aber nichts weiter als ein bedeutungsloses Klangwort, das hauptsächlich im Umgang mit Kindern (und daher auch von Kindern) benutzt wird)

Comment: Der Begriff ist vor allem im Rheinland gebräuchlich. Zur Herkunft kenne ich allerdings keine belastbaren Quellen.

Comment: Mir - gebürtiger Saarländer - ist der Terminus Heiopei schon seit früher Kindheit bekannt.

Comment: Im Emsland auch gängig.

Comment: In case anybody stumbles upon this: I closed and reopened this question for science.

Comment: Bei Goethes „ Egmond“ kommt es vor

Answer (score 6):

Mich hat dieses Wort sofort an das Schweizerdeutsche *Heie poppeie* erinnert.

Im [schweizerischen Idiotikon](http://www.idiotikon.ch/) ist dieser Begriff in diversen [Varianten](http://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id2.htm#!page/20853/mode/1up) aufgeführt. Allerdings dienen alle Varianten dem Ausdruck von, zumeist positiven, Gefühlen, der Ermutigung oder anderen lautmalerischen Unterstützungen von Situationen. Als Bezeichnung für irgendwelche Personengruppen wird es dort **nicht** verwendet.

Answer (score 4):

Die beiden Ausdrücke scheinen nichts miteinander zu tun zu haben. *Heia popeia* ist ein Überbleibsel einer byzantinischen Prinzessin, die einen Österreicher heiratete.
Aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodora_Angela_(Byzanz)):

> Theodora Angela Prinzessin von Byzanz, Herzogin von Österreich (* zwischen 1180 und 1185, † 22./23. Juni 1246 in Kahlenberg) war als Gemahlin von Leopold VI. dem Glorreichen von Österreich Herzogin von Österreich und Steiermark, wurde als Witwe Zisterzienserin im Stift Lilienfeld.
>
> […]
>
> Anzunehmen ist auch, das etwas von der griechischen Lebensart und Kultur am Wiener Hof Eingang gefunden hat und sie vielleicht sogar einen Beitrag zur deutschen Folklore geleistet hat, da vermutlich der Refrain des populären Kinderliedes „Heia popeia“ auf Theodora zurückgeht. Laut kommt es von altgriechisch 'Hoide o paide' = 'schlaf, o Kind', das umgangssprachlich abgeschliffen wurde.

Zu Herkunft von *Heiopei* [sei laut Redensarten-Index nichts bekannt](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~ein%20Heiopei&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)

Comment: Erstaunlich! Von 'Hoide o paide' kommt nämlich auf jeden Fall "Heidschi Bumbeidschi", ein ganz anderes Kinderlied. (Und viel näher an der tatsächlichen mittel- (nicht alt-)griechischen Aussprache von 'Hoide mou paide'.) Ich kann in der auf Wikipedia angegebenen Quelle auch nichts zu "Heia Popeia" finden.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin in meinem Russischkurs auf das Wort gestoßen. Das russische Wort "schalopai" (шалопай) heißt umgangssprachlich Taugenichts. Und das erinnerte mich sehr an das mir aus dem Ruhrpott/Westfälischen bekannte Heiopei.

Comment: Das bringt uns bei der Suche nach zuverlässigen Quellen nicht wirklich weiter; es ist kaum mehr als ein Kommentar.

Comment: @Jan Die Herkunft aus anderen Sprachen ist ein wichtiger Hinweis, auch wenn vlt. nicht als Antwort geeignet, aber es kann sehr wichtig sein, dein Ton ist etwas arg hier. ;-)